# Changing the default config for modules that will be shown in menuconfig and others

Tags: module, linux-kernel, kernel, config

I was wondering whether there is a way to change the configuration or default values somewhere which will change the default values for modules shown in the menuconfig.

I found out that the the file "source/scripts/kconfig/confdata.c" is used to write the config options in the .config file. It uses a structure called `rootmenu` to read the symbols for each module and write them accordingly.
But where does it pick it from. Lets suppose I want to change the default values only, which the confdata.c file picks up, so that I do not have to change in menuconfig.

Comment: The defaults are set in the various Kconfig* files scattered throughout the source directories.

Comment: @IanAbbott, Any way or tracking a particular one. Any pattern they follow?

Comment: You can use the search (`/`) facility within `make menuconfig` (or `Edit` -> `Find` in `make xconfig`) to search for configuration options. They will default to `n` unless selected manually or automatically selected by some other option or by the existing `.config`.

Comment: @IanAbbott, The thing is, I don't have access to `make menuconfig`. I will have to find a way to enable a certain module from the kconfig files itself..

Comment: You would have to `make` some sort of `*config` target to process the Kconfig files. `make config` is the most basic utility for editing the config.

Comment: You can also use `*_defconfig` files to hold a set of non-default configuration settings for a particular target system. Use `make savedefconfig` to convert the current `.config` to a minimal `defconfig` file and copy that `defconfig` to `arch/${ARCH}/configs/myspecialboard_defconfig`. You can then run `make myspecialboard_defconfig` to produce a `.config` file with your special settings applied.

Answer (score 0):

First you need `$ linux/.config` You can copy `/boot/config-x.y.z` Like so, if you in the top level directory of the kernel source, `linux` or so `$ cp /boot/config-x.y.z .` Once you have .config in the sources directory, that's the config file for that kernel source.

You can search it like a text file like so, `$ grep KEYS .config` So, if the thing you want to change, and I'm only talking about removing, that will tell you  if the word KEY all caps is in the file.

Then you can open `.config` and search for your item, and delete it. Then it won't be included in the kernel configuration at all. You must run `$ make oldconfig` to make it official.

If you just want to control whether or not a module is included in the kernel, you must configure it using `$ make menuconfig` , `$ make xconfig` or , if you're a glutton for boredom, `make config`

Then you can tell the kernel exactly what you want in it, and not. There is a reason the config file is not usually edited manually. So, I don't advise it. Just configure the kernel with one of the make commands above.

If you need more assistance, ask!

After you're finished with the configuration, you run `$ make`